# ggplot y axis adjustment and statistics

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am running a barplot using the `mtcars` data set adding statistics on for
group comparison. Using below code I get the statistical comparison with **

```
ggbarplot(
  mtcars, x = "am", y = "mpg",
  add = "mean_sd",fill = "black",
  xlab = "AM",
  ylab="Fuel consumption (Miles/ Gallon)"
) +
  stat_compare_means(
    comparisons = list(c("0", "1")), 
    label = "p.signif"
  ) + scale_x_discrete(labels= c(0,1))
```

However, I want to adjust the ylim. When I run the code below the statistical comparison is lost (i guess moved out of view). 
Is there anyway of adjusting ylim and keeping the stats in view

```
ggbarplot(
  mtcars, x = "am", y = "mpg",
  add = "mean_sd",fill = "black",
  xlab = "AM",
  ylab="Fuel consumption (Miles/ Gallon)",ylim=c(0,30)
) +
  stat_compare_means(
    comparisons = list(c("0", "1")), 
    label = "p.signif"
  ) + scale_x_discrete(labels= c(0,1))
```

Comment: Try `label.y = 30` in `stat_compare_means`. I have tried with `31` and it is not visible.

Comment: that has worked thanks!